# How do I fix this corrupted page?

Tags: sql-server-2005, dbcc, corruption, data-pages

My database is in simple recovery mode. One page got corrupted and I only have backups created using simple backup.

When I run this:

```
DBCC PAGE ('myDB', 1, 952663, 3)
```

I get:

```
DBCC PAGE error: Invalid page type - dump style 3 not possible.

SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:952663; actual 2668:-1594740640). It occurred during a read of page (1:952663) in database ID 5 at offset 

Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 332114207834112 (type Unknown), page ID (1:952663) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = (2668:-1594740640).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1131971209, index ID 1, partition ID 72057595034861568, alloc unit ID 72057595204796416 (type In-row data): Page (1:952663) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1131971209, index ID 1, partition ID 72057595034861568, alloc unit ID 72057595204796416 (type In-row data). Page (1:952663) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:1616550) and previous (1:2296409) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1131971209, index ID 1, partition ID 72057595034861568, alloc unit ID 72057595204796416 (type In-row data). Page (1:1743775) is missing a reference from previous page (1:952663). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 2511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1131971209, index ID 25, partition ID 72057595034796032, alloc unit ID 72057595204730880 (type In-row data). Keys out of order on page (1:3474431), slots 237 and 238.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in table 'TransactionEntry' (object ID 1131971209).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 5 consistency errors in database 'DsPointOfSale'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DsPointOfSale).
```

Can I still repair this database?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64595/discussion-on-question-by-ezi-how-do-i-fix-this-corrupted-page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is the clustered index affected. If it was me I'd probably try DBCC PAGE ('myDB', 1, 952663, 2); on both the restored backup and the broken DB first to see and compare in Winmerge to see if I could infer anything from that (e.g. if both very similar but just some corruption in the page header then you could use DBCC with style 3 on the restored DB to get a good idea of specific rows to restore after REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS. Otherwise you'll just need to do a data compare between the two tables and try and see if you can figure out rows that need restoring that way. – Martin Smith